# Turtle bgpic() not displaying image and giving me these error messages…?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to get Turtle-graphics to display a background image.

Here's my code:

```
import turtle
from turtle import *
from appJar import gui
...
turtle.setup(900,700)       #windowsize
Ian = turtle.Turtle()
Ian.hideturtle()
Ian.screen.title("Arp Convertor")
Ian.screen.bgcolor("#4a4a54")           
Ian.screen.bgpic('Backwslots2.gif')
Ian.speed(0)
Ian.penup()                             #dont draw
Ian.goto(-430,250)                      #where we'll start drawing
```

My image is the right size, exactly 900x700 in the current dir (same as my .py file).   But the bgpic() line is giving me these errors.

```
> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File
> "C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
> line 1705, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)   File "D:\Midipy\appJar\appjar.py", line 3574, in <lambda>
>     return lambda *args: funcName(param)   File "midipy.py", line 21, in openthefile
>     convertthefile(btn)   File "midipy.py", line 141, in convertthefile
>     Ian.screen.bgpic('Backwslots2.gif')   File "C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\turtle.py",
> line 1482, in bgpic
>     self._setbgpic(self._bgpic, self._bgpics[picname])   File "C:\Users\Ian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\turtle.py",
> line 738, in _setbgpic
>     self.cv.itemconfig(item, image=image)
```

Comment: You chopped off the traceback before the point where it gave the actual error message.

Comment: **Here's the rest of the error message:**

> File "<string>", line 1, in itemconfig   File
> "C:\Users\Nesbitt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
> line 2578, in itemconfigure
>     return self._configure(('itemconfigure', tagOrId), cnf, kw)   File "C:\Users\Nesbitt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
> line 1476, in _configure
>     self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
> _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage4" doesn't exist

Comment: You appear to have somehow created more than one instance of the Tkinter GUI environment that the Turtle module uses - presumably this happened somewhere in code that you left out.  Tkinter images are created in the first-created instance by default, and cannot be displayed in any other instance.

Comment: My program has a GUI open where it loads a file in, then a Turtle window is invoked.  Is this the two environments you're talking about?  How would I get around this conflict?   Here's an image of what it looks like:  https://i.imgur.com/jxKaiMU.jpg

Comment: It looks like appJar has its own turtle widget; using that, instead of the `turtle` module directly, would presumably fix the problem.

Comment: I actually changed it to  `Ian.screen.bgpic(None)`  and it worked OK.  So its calling bgpic() without any conflict there.  Maybe its the path to my background image, or its dimensions, type of GIF... or something else?

Comment: When I close the appjar window, with app.stop() and run it, the conflict goes away.  so you were right,  thanks.